# Office Add-in, using Node JS, and Graph with SSO, how do I actually make a new call?

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, office-js

I have been looking into connecting a Word Add-in to SharePoint list data using a task pane.

I have completed the following two tutorials that guide you through creating an add in that uses SSO to access user data and then update the add-in to get data from one drive instead.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/sso-quickstart
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/sso-quickstart-customize

However, these tutorials have you edit the .ENV file with a new GRAPH_URL_SEGMENT and SCOPE etc, however I see no reference to how editing the ENV would actually effect anything, no code that makes use of this information and no details of when the call using the Graph api is actually made and what configuration it uses.

I have been able to get a call working to SharePoint in the graph explorer but cannot move that over to the word add-in.

Could someone please help me understand where the calls endpoint is used to make the Graph call and how someone would go about to change this to make a call to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to get Microsoft Graph data is in the library office-addin-sso. Specifically, the files \node_modules\office-addin-sso\src\app.ts and \node_modules\office-addin-sso\src\authRoute.ts

You will see in those files where the ENV variables are read.

To get your SharePoint data, use the URL you constructed in the Graph Explorer to set the GRAPH_URL_SEGMENT and the QUERY_PARAM_SEGMENT in the ENV file. Also, update the SCOPE variable in that file as needed. See the section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/sso-quickstart-customize#changes-required-for-any-type-of-add-in for an example.

You will also need to update the permissions you request in the Azure portal as described in this section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/sso-quickstart-customize#update-app-permissions-in-azure

Comment: Hi Rick, Thanks for answering.
I've seen your profile alot on the documentation etc :)

This example of changing the ENV file would allow me to make a single call to SharePoint, can I just ask if you could point me on the right direction to make another call in the same solution? For example a get request to SharePoint then a Post As far as I can see the ENV file setup would only allow for 1 call to be made, which is quite different that REST api types I have used in the past.

Comment: I see what you mean. The project produced by Yo Office doesn't give the add-in any way to call to multiple different Graph endpoints. I think you should raise this as an issue on the repo for the template that Yo Office uses for SSO projects: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane-SSO-JS/issues

Comment: Hi Rick,
I tied going to the report for the template and have not yet received any response, unless i'm mistaken the repo is not actively being monitored anymore.
I posted the following:https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane-SSO-JS/issues/25

Is there anything you can do to point my in the right direction? I need to be able to make multiple different calls to graph (both get and post) from the same addin

Comment: See my response to your repo issue.

Comment: Hi Rick,
Thank you.